# Converting JSON to model instance in Django

Tags: django, json, deserialization

What's the best way in django to update a model instance given a json representation of that model instance.

Is using deserialize the correct approach? Are there tutorials available out there?

Comment: Have you looked at [this page on serialization of models in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)?

Comment: Yes - but i'm having difficulty with it. the json object i'm passing to the server doesn't have all the data in the model just a portion of it (including the pk of course). And I want to update the model based on that code.

Answer (score 13):

The best approach would be to utilize one of the [existing Django applications](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/) that support serializing model instances to and from JSON.

In either case, if you parse the JSON object to a Python dictionary, you can basically use the [`QuerySet.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) method directly.

So, say you get a dictionary where all the keys map to model attributes and they represent the values you'd want to update, you could do this:

```
updates = {                                    # Our parsed JSON data
    'pk': 1337,
    'foo': 'bar', 
    'baz': 192.05
}

id = updates.pop('pk')                         # Extract the instance's ID
Foo.objects.filter(id=id).update(**updates)    # Update the instance's data
```