# Storing JSON into sqlite database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am posting a JSON object back to the server side and retrieving that information through a request. Right now this is my code for my **views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rawdata = request.body
        JSONData= json.dumps(rawdata)
    return HttpResponse(rawdata)
```

when I return rawdata my response looks like this:

```
[{"time_elapsed":"0","volts":"239.3","amps":"19.3","kW":"4.618","kWh":"0","session":"1"},...]
```

when I return JSONdata my response looks like this:

```
"[{\"time_elapsed\":\"0\",\"volts\":\"239.1\",\"amps\":\"20.8\",\"kW\":\"4.973\",\"kWh\":\"0\",\"session\":\"1\"},....]
```

which response is better when trying to insert this data into a sqlite database using Python/Django?

Also how would I start a loop for this do I have to do this kind of code?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT STATEMENTS")
```

I assume I have to do a loop for the INSERT STATEMENTS portion of that code, but I don't have any key to work off of. In my data everything between {} is one row. How do I iterate through this array saying everytime you see {...data...} insert it into a new row?

Comment: Why are you storing JSON like that in a SQLite database?  Usually you would have a model for that.  I understand the appeal of SQLite, but you might want to look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), which uses JSON for documents.

Comment: I'm just learning all this. I was given an end goal and I am slowly working my way through it. This is what I have been able to do by myself and lots of help from those around me and on this site. Based on this comment and one answer I guess I don't understand what a ModelForm is or how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I eventually solved my problem. It was a matter of figuring out how to translate the JSON object to something python could recognize and then writing a simple loop to iterate through all the data that was produced.

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rawdata1 = request.body
        rawdata2 = json.loads(rawdata1)
        length = len(rawdata2)
        for i in range(0,length,1):
            x = meterdata(time_elapsed=rawdata2[i]['time_elapsed'], volts=rawdata2[i]['volts'], amps=rawdata2[i]['amps'], kW=rawdata2[i]['kW'], kWh=rawdata2[i]['kWh'], session=rawdata2[i]['session'])
            x.save()        
    return HttpResponse("Success!")
```

The big differences is the json.loads rather than dumps and in the for loop how to access the newly converted data. The first bracket specifies the row to look in and the second specifies what item to look for. for the longest time I was trying to do data[0][0]. May this help anyone who finds this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

probably if you need to store that data in a db is best to create a model representing it, then you create a `ModelForm` with associated your model for handling your POST.

In this manner saving the model to the db is trivial and serializing it as a json response is something like

```
data = serializers.serialize('json',
                             YourModel.objects.filter(id=id),
                             fields=('list','of','fields'))

return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: I do have a model written for this. The model mimics the format of the JSON object exactly. Is there a tutorial or example you could link for using ModelForms? What I don't understand is I am not really using a form. The data that I have is randomly generated into an HTML table then read into a JSON object off the HTML table. None of it is user created.

Comment: you could skip the modelform part, take a look at this answer for a hint on how to deal with external json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487447/converting-json-to-model-instance-in-django